# Unfocused ListBox, item style

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, styles, focus

OK, I can't believe there is no online resources about this. I want to do a simple thing and change style of a `ListBox` item when it's selected and it's parent `ListBox` has lost focus.

We have been using `VisualStateManager` for this purpose, but since there is overlapping in `Selected`, `SelectedFocused` and `Focused` states, there were some bugs introduced when selecting items holding ctrl for example(wrong items appear selected).  I decided to fix it using `Trigger`s and found out that there seems to be no way of triggering when `ListBox` lost focus.

My question is what is the right way of implementing this behavior, and **please don't say** "override SystemColors"...

EDIT:

OK, I have up-voted both answers but picked Viv's response because his answer makes it work exactly like original `ListBox` while I don't have problems with mouse-over and other styles I already use. I have already seen usage of `Selector` attached property, but never tried `IsSelectionActive`, it worked like a charm. I would recommend going for triggers for this type of problem, although the `VisualStateManager` is newer in WPF. I think there are clearly some problems with overlapping states that can be avoided.

Thanks again to Viv and Richard for providing great examples of 2 ways of implementing the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> OK, I can't believe there is no online resources about this. I want to do a simple thing and change style of a ListBox item when it's selected and it's parent ListBox has lost focus.

guess your looking for a `MultiTrigger` with `IsSelected=true` and `Selector.IsSelectionActive=false`?

so something like:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ListBox Margin="15">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Blue" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                          Value="true" />
              <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                          Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Red" />
          </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="B" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
  </ListBox>
  <ListBox Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="15">
    <ListBoxItem Content="A" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="B" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="C" />
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Now when an item in the left `ListBox` is selected and then if the actual `ListBox` looses focus, it would get a Red `Foreground` like:

[image]

`Foreground` is just an example, using the `MultiTrigger` you can tweak the `Style` as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `Style` for the `ListBoxItem` that used the `VisualStateManager`. It highlights the items in the manner that I would expect.

```
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Padding="2">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                 Value="DodgerBlue"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                 Value="CornflowerBlue"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Yes this uses only SelectionStates... The problem is I have FocusStates that overlap with SelectionStates. I think I might live without them, will give it a try, and let you know if it works OK.